Safe Glossy Non-Toxic Finish for Wood Shifter Handle?
I'm considering getting a custom wood shifter handle and they can either do a raw finish, a semi-glossy finish or glossy polished. Just wondering what the safest and least toxic glossy finish would be to use? Or is it better with no finish?
Thanks for any help!

When you say “non-toxic”, do you mean during application, or after it’s cured? I believe most finishes are non-toxic once they cure. (Will you be the one applying the finish?)

See here: https://blog.lostartpress.com/2020/11/30/rip-the-anarchists-finishing-manual/, under the “Finishes That Want You Dead or Sick – or at Least Irritated” section. This is a good overview from a safety-conscious (paranoid?) perspective.

Help me out here, a shifter is a gear stick in British English yes? If that's so for me at least the super glossy 'deep' finish is the only way to go. Grip: people will argue endlessly about whether bare wood or a glossy applied finish are best; you'll have to wade through all that for yourself because that's not really a Q for Woodworking. In terms of toxicity, this is completely a non-issue; the only areas where this is even remotely an issue are baby and children's toys, and in a food-prep arena. In terms of skin contact there is ZERO to worry about... especially in this context!

@stanch, that Lost Art Press page is a good read and has tons of good stuff in it, but even after such a short interval it's already out of date in some key details. The preponderance of BLOs that are now just a "heat-bodied oil" is now much higher than it was only 3-4 years ago. The heavy-metal driers in BLO were really a bit of a red herring issue anyway, but things are just easier when they're no longer in the picture, and multiple non-boutique brands (on both sides of the Atlantic) no longer use driers. [The MS commentary that immediately follows is grossly misplaced, and inaccurate.]

Thanks @Graphus! I did venture to suggest it was a bit paranoid :) On MS (Mineral Spirits / White Spirits?) — which I’ve gathered from your comments you are fond of — is the inaccuracy that it’s not “out to kill us”? I am still wary/unclear on the dangers (if any) of that stuff, as well as turpentine, liquid paraffin and other distillates.

@stanch, a couple of issues with the mention in that context. To start with think it might be an exaggeration to say most thin, although I don't know (and I strongly suspect Chris doesn't either and was writing off the cuff; so I'm sure this wasn't intentionally to mislead, but still). The mention of benzene on the other hand is a gross error, simple as that. I believe this might be our hale fellow Schwarz mixing up the common ethanol denaturing additive used in the US with the basic distillates present in a typical MS. If he did intentionally include it however an alarmist warning [contd]

...of a cancer risk from a product where said carcinogen is present as merely a contaminant (absolutely TINY levels, 0.1% or much less) is California-level alarmism. Especially in the context of non-occupational use, which he quite rightly addresses elsewhere as a balancing observation in other contexts.
